# Access control on other page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to access control in other aspx page from other aspx page in asp.net

Comment: Use session instead. Their is no other way you can access it

Answer (score 1):

you can use [findcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

Example to get the textbox text:

```
string   controlValue =((TextBox)( Page.FindControl("uc").FindControl("TextBox1"))).Text;
```

Note: us is id of `usercontrol` registered in the aspx page. `TextBox1` is the textbox in the usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = ((Button)PreviousPage.FindControl("Button1"));
Button1.Text = btn.Text;
```

Use : [PreviousPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Note : PreviousPage property Gets the page that transferred control to the current page.